# Xamarin + RabbitMq localhost connection problem

Tags: xamarin, .net-core, rabbitmq, rawrabbit

I have mobile app in Xamarin.Forms (android) + .Net core API. We figured out how to debug mobile requests over locally hosted API by using kestrel and proper launch settings (same wifi network). 
Now I have problem with access to local RabitMq server. 
I used RawRabbit wrapper for because it gives nice and easy fluent configuration.
Current config:

```
var config = new RawRabbitConfiguration
        {
            Username = "test",
            Password = "test",
            VirtualHost = "/",
            Port = 5672,
            Hostnames = new List<string>() { "10.0.0.5" },
            RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            PublishConfirmTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            RecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            PersistentDeliveryMode = true,
            AutoCloseConnection = false,
            AutomaticRecovery = true,
            TopologyRecovery = true,
            Exchange = new GeneralExchangeConfiguration()
            {
                Type = ExchangeType.Topic,
                AutoDelete = false,
                Durable = true,
            }
        };
```

The exception is just Timeout.
Is there a possibility to allow access for this Ip/Port over whole local network?
NOTE: I have added firewall rules to allow In/Out port 5672, same result.

Thanks in advance for any tip